# Infinite scroll of tabular data for MooTools

Tags: javascript, html, mootools, infinite-scroll

Is there a robust MooTools based JavaScript library for implementing infinite scroll of tabular data?

So think of an Excel spreadsheet that you display partial data on (maybe 10000 rows) - we show 500 rows initially, and scroll downward and then load the next 500 rows. Additionally, as needed we may need to drop the "first" rows off in case the dom is too huge.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a library for this sort of data manipulation/render.

If your data is contained in a javascript Array:

```
var dataArray = [
    [1, 5, 7, 9],
    [3, 6, 2, 86],
    [77, 3, 5, 14],
    ...
];
```

You only need to iterate through the array and render the rows as necessary.

```
function renderRows(startIndex, endIndex) {
    dataArray.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
    var numRows = dataArray.length;
    for(x=0;x<numRows;x++) {
        renderRow(dataArray[x]);
    }
}

function renderRow(data) {
    new Element('tr', {
        // ...
    }).inject(table);
}
```

Likewise, if you need to prune the table:

```
function pruneTable(number) {
    // assuming "table" is defined elsewhere and points to the <table> element
    var rows = table.getElements('tr');
    for(x=0;x<number;x++) rows[x].destroy();
}
```

This same set of functions can be easily modified to make ajax calls to "get" a set of *n* rows, and render them as they come in, etc etc.

Mootools isn't the end, it's simple a means to an end!

**Caveat**: This is all untested. I take no responsibility for any syntax errors!

Comment: So what if I *don't* have the capability to store all the rows of data in memory at one time. How does this solution scroll?

Comment: AJAX it up. You don't have to store the entire data set, and can make an AJAX call to pull newer entries on demand.

Comment: Right. I'm doing that now in terms of how I get data now. What I'm looking for are simple modules that implement this technique, such as http://www.infinite-scroll.com/ . Your answer is very general, and at the moment doesn't get me anything that's not obvious. What I'm looking for is clean implementations, perhaps as a MooTools plugin, that allow me to specify a datasource, code to transform that into html, and rules for when to trigger fetching new data.